# JPA - How to achieve this SQL behaviour (left join parent entity to previously inner joined child & grand child entities)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jpql, heroku-connect

I'm not being able to find out the way to achieve desired result with JPA/JPQL as I'm with this SQL query:

```
select parent.id, child.id, grandchild.id
from salesforce.parent__c parent 
left outer join salesforce.child__c child  
inner join salesforce.grandchild grandchild on child.grandchild_id__c=grandchild.sfid 
and (grandchild.token__c='....') 
on parent.sfid=child.parent_id__c
where (parent.external_id__c is not null) 
and parent.displayed__c=true 
and parent.internal__c=false 
and parent.date__c>='....' 
and parent.date__c<='....' 
order by parent.date__c asc
```

The target output of the query I'm looking for would be something like this:

```
Parent  Child   Grandchild
P1  null    null
P2  null    null
P3  C1  GC1
P4  C2  GC2
```

Where all records from parent meet parent's filters, and a child record is not returned unless its grandchild meets gc's filters.

My best guess on JPQL would be something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Parent p 
LEFT JOIN p.childs cl 
INNER JOIN cl.grandchilds c 
ON c.token__c = '....' 
ON cl.parent__c = p.sfid 
WHERE p.external_id__c IS NOT NULL 
AND p.displayed__c = true 
AND p.internal__c = false 
AND p.date__c >= '....' 
AND p.date__c <= '....' 
ORDER BY p.date__c asc
```

But this is throwing `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON`

The way i'm doing the query i assume is just OK:

```
String queryTxt = "SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Parent p LEFT JOIN p.childs cl INNER JOIN cl.grandchilds c ON c.token__c = '....' ON cl.parent__c = p.sfid WHERE p.external_id__c IS NOT NULL AND p.displayed__c = true AND p.internal__c = false AND p.date__c >= '....' AND p.date__c <= '....' ORDER BY p.date__c asc";
TypedQuery<Parent> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(queryTxt, Parent.class);
List<Parent> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

If I try with the following JPQL it executes fine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Parent p 
LEFT JOIN p.childs cl 
INNER JOIN cl.grandchilds c 
ON c.token__c = '....' 
WHERE p.external_id__c IS NOT NULL 
AND p.displayed__c = true 
AND p.internal__c = false 
AND p.date__c >= '....' 
AND p.date__c <= '....' 
ORDER BY p.date__c asc
```

But the results are not what i'm looking for, as the inner join between child and grandchild is filtering out as well parent records:

```
Parent  Child   Grandchild
P3    C1    GC1
P4    C2    GC2
```

I've also tried with `Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(strQuery, Parent.class);` using the SQL query on the beginning of the post, replacing the select part with parent.*, child.*, grandchild.*, but then I'm not being able to parse full structure properly either :-\

Answer (score 0):

You can do any query with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Fundamentals#postgresql-inner-join) and use its [Tuple](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Entities-&-Tuples) support for projections. Provide me your entities and I will draft you the full solution.